# Codeigniter query returns record with null id. Which shouldn't be possible

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time already. I tried searching for an answer in stackoverflow, google and other sources but I didn't manage to find something that could lead me to the solution of the problem. I really hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Im using Codeigniter 3

My query in codeigniter is as shown here bellow:

```
  $this->db->select($fields)
        ->from("usuario as u")
        ->join("usuario_info as ui ", "ui.idusuario = u.idusuario","left");
    $this->db->where("usua_url",$this->url_usuario);
    return $this->db->get();  //last line
```

I do get results from the query with data from a record which has an id (in the database is a `PK` and can't be `NULL`

My compiled query from `CI` is:

```
SELECT * FROM `usuario` as `u` LEFT JOIN `usuario_info` as `ui` ON `ui`.`idusuario` = `u`.`idusuario` WHERE `usua_url` = 'heri'
```

And my result is the following after applying `result_array` method (I censored some field names and its values, you know..):

```
array(9) { 
    ["idusuario"]=> NULL 
    ["other_field1"]=> string(9) "censored"                    
    ["other_field2"]=> string(60) "censored" 
    ["other_field3"]=> string(26) "censored"
    ["other_field4"]=> string(19) "censored"                                                         
   `["other_field5"]=> string(7) "censored" 
    ["other_field6"]=> string(4) "censored"             
    ["other_field7"]=> NULL 
    ["other_field"]=> NULL 
 }`
```

When I copy and paste exactly the same query into DataGrip or Workbench I get the same results except for `idusuario`, the results look like:

```
array(9) { 
    ["idusuario"]=> 1 
    ["other_field1"]=> string(9) "censored"                    
    ["other_field2"]=> string(60) "censored" 
    ["other_field3"]=> string(26) "censored"
    ["other_field4"]=> string(19) "censored"                                                         
   `["other_field5"]=> string(7) "censored" 
    ["other_field6"]=> string(4) "censored"             
    ["other_field7"]=> NULL 
    ["other_field"]=> NULL 
 }`
```

Comment: First of all, is 'idusuario' field present in both usuario and usuario_info tables. If yes, then you can use $fields=  idusuario.*, usuario_info.fld1, usuario_info.fld2, usuario_info.fld3, ... so that usuario_info table's column data does not replace the same named colum's data of usuario table.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for that, but if they are the same, would it be a problem if one table's field replaces another (they are pk and fk)?

Comment: You are doing a left join. If the data in second table does not exists, in mysql query result you will get - tbl1.id={id}, tbl2.id=NULL. But when it is parsed into php assoc array, $result['id'] will become NULL from the second tbl2(it will replace the first tbl1's value). In order to eliminate this sort of issue(if happens for any row), I suggested the previous way :)

Answer (score 0):

Well after trying something I thought wouldn't make any difference I got to the solution.

I had a method like for the query like this:

```
public function selectPerfilInfo($fields = "*"){
    $this->db->select($fields);
    $this->db->from("usuario as u");
    $this->db->join("usuario_info as ui ", "ui.idusuario = u.idusuario","left");
    $this->db->where("usua_url",$this->url_usuario);
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

I was calling it like this in my controller:

```
//before calling the method I already set the `url_usuario` attribute of my class
$this->my_controller->selectPerfilInfo();
```

I changed the line above to this:

```
$this->my_controller->selectPerfilInfo("u.idusuario, u.other_field1");
```

After passing the specific fields to the function it returns the right results.
Im not sure why it happens and this leaves me a lot of doubts because I have used the same structure for getting records from other tables with no problems.

I'd appreciate if any of you could give me any information about it. Thanks